# How can I tell Jest through the command line not to run a certain test file, but run all others?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, jestjs

I have three test files, `acceptance.test.js` `routes.test.js` `snapshots.test.js`

I want to create an npm script in my package.json that would ignore one of these test files when it's used. I'm trying to use the Jest option `--testPathPattern` to do this. For example:

```
  "scripts": {
    "no-snapshots-test": "jest --coverage --testPathPattern=^(?!snapshots).*$"
  }
```

This particular example gives an error of `.*$ was unexpected at this time` in the terminal, though. I've tried removing .*$ off the end, but that causes my snapshot tests to still run.

What's the correct regex to allow me to specify the file (or files) that I want to ignore? I need to do this in the CLI, so I can't use the Jest config option testPathIgnorePattern.

Comment: You can load a config using the `--config=` cli argument. Isn't that an option?

Comment: Hi @Andy - do you have an example of a proper Jest config? I've tried using the testPathIgnorePatterns option in a Jest config file and it successfully ignores that file, but then I get an error in my acceptance tests that some of the strings I'm matching are not strings. This is only happening when I ignore my snapshot tests, not when I run the full test suite.

Answer (score 0):

The beginning `^` and the end `$` are not supported. Omit them and use the very same Regex without the negative lookahead:

```
"scripts": {
    "no-snapshots-test": "jest --coverage --testPathPattern=snapshots.*"
}
```

Just a guess: you might need to use the proper JavaScript Regex syntax: `/snapshots.*/g`.

Comment: Do you separate file names using commas, spaces or the `|` operator?

Comment: Follow the standard Regex notation to match multiple files

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use a negative lookahead in the `testPathPattern` you can use the the `testPathIgnorePattern` instead. It is not documented in the jest CLI documentation but it still works.

```
"scripts": {
    "no-snapshots-test": "jest --coverage --testPathIgnorePattern=snapshots"
  }
```

You might need to change the ignore pattern though if it matches too many of your tests.